# Wrong encoding (csv file + mysql)

Tags: python

I have a problem with encoding.

my *csv file* (encoding UTF-8):

> Id,Title,FullDescription
>   55408086,Injection Moulding Product Designer,• Tooling experience is an advantage • Automotive experience is as must

and my *python code* (simplified):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import codecs

with codecs.open('D:\\Downloads\\Train_rev2.csv', 'rb', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    data.next()
    for row in data:
        print (row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

This prints:

> ('55408086', 'Injection Moulding Product Designer', '\xe2\x80\xa2 Tooling experience is an advantage \xe2\x80\xa2 Automotive experience is as must')

Then I insert the data to database (*MYSQL* with encoding UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)) and I am getting there data with wrong encoding:

```
55408086,Injection Moulding Product Designer,â€¢ Tooling experience is an advantage â€¢ Automotive experience is as must
```

Comment: Python 2.x or 3.x? Can you show us a demo of a matched MySQL entry and a CSV entry. So we can relate to what the original data is. With Python 2.x try something like `import codecs` `row[0].encode('utf-8')` etc. and it will convert to UTF-8 Latin ISO-8859-1

Comment: @Allendar, Python 2.7.
Csv file: "55408086,Injection Moulding Product Designer,• Tooling experience is an advantage • Automotive experience is as must"
but I got "55408086,Injection Moulding Product Designer,â€¢ Tooling experience is an advantage â€¢ Automotive experience is as must" in MySQL

Comment: Sadly I can't reproduce; at my end everything looks great in Python 2.7. Can do some prints and see from which point the string get's messed up? Or try `import codecs` `print(trains[0].decode("utf-8"))` There are invalid ASCII characters tho; `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)` when trying to encode the data to UTF-8.

Comment: When I try use decode("utf-8") I am getting error UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2022' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: The printed string looks fine (it's UTF-8 encoded). If you want to display correctly, try `print "%s, %s, %s" (row[0], row[1], row[2])"`. But how are you sending this to the database?